# What effect does using border radius have?

Tags: design-principles, borders

I am interested in knowing why rounding corners of a shape is visually appealing in some contexts. What's the reason behind it and in what types of context does it help to use it?

Comment: Hi and welcome Nic! I edited your question to make it less opinion based. Please make sure it still matches the question you want to ask and feel free to edit again if need be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round corners make things look friendlier and softer. Smooth curved surfaces evoke health and youth.

Pointy corners give a feeling of sharp jaggedness.

Round corners add to the flow of a page and make elements balance with each other (if they have the same amount or roundness)

On the other hand, straight corners look clean, sleek and modern. They evoke order and efficient tidiness.

Round corners look bubbly and child like, playful and safe.

With a shape like a square or hexagon, round corners make it look smooth and worn down.

I, apparently have ancient, primal associations with round = good and pointy = bad.